# What is the command getweb?

Tags: command-line, printing

I found on this launchpad bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/foo2zjs/+bug/96454) the command:

```
sudo getweb 1020
```

I don't know what getweb is, so here is the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a tool to download from the internet various printer related things: e.g. firmware. Specifically `sudo getweb 1020` is to `Get HP LJ 1020 firmware file`. You get the text below if you run `getweb` (without arguments) in a terminal.

`Convenience script to get extra somethings from the web, such as ICC color profiles, firmware, PPD files, etc.`